# how to cumulative sum variable by unique values and input back in

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I'm looking to do the following -- cumulative sum the indicator values and remove the indicators after those days
original:

| transaction | day | indicator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 | 1 |

and make the new table like this --

| transaction | day | indicator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

Change all day with indicator == 1 to the first day with indicator == 1

```
df%>%
  group_by(transaction)%>%
  mutate(day=case_when(indicator==0~day,
                       T~head(day[indicator==1],1)))%>%
  group_by(transaction,day)%>%
  summarise(indicator=sum(indicator))%>%
  ungroup

  transaction   day indicator
        <int> <int>     <int>
1           1     1         0
2           1     2         0
3           1     3         0
4           1     4         3
5           2     1         0
6           2     2         0
7           2     3         0
8           2     4         0
9           2     5         2
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

### code

```r
df <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% group_by(transaction) %>% 
mutate(cumsum=cumsum(indicator), cumsum2=ifelse(cumsum==1, day, NA)) %>% 
fill(cumsum2) %>% 
mutate(day=ifelse(!is.na(cumsum2), cumsum2, day)) %>% 
group_by(transaction, day) %>% slice_tail(n=1) %>% select(-cumsum2)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### output

```r
# A tibble: 8 × 4
# Groups:   transaction, day [8]
  transaction   day indicator cumsum
        <dbl> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1           1     1         0      0
2           1     2         0      0
3           1     3         0      0
4           1     4         1      3
5           2     1         0      0
6           2     2         0      0
7           2     3         0      0
8           2     4         1      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to try. After grouping by `transaction`, change `indicator` to either 0 (same) or the `sum` of `indicator`. Finally, keep or `filter` previous rows where `cumall` (cumulative all) values for `indicator` are 0. Using `lag` will provide the last row containing the sum.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(transaction) %>%
  mutate(indicator = ifelse(indicator == 0, 0, sum(indicator))) %>%
  filter(cumall(lag(indicator, default = 0) == 0))
```

**Output**

```
  transaction   day indicator
        <int> <int>     <dbl>
1           1     1         0
2           1     2         0
3           1     3         0
4           1     4         3
5           2     1         0
6           2     2         0
7           2     3         0
8           2     4         0
9           2     5         2
```